# Can't find Angry Birds

Tags: google-play-store

Same [websites](http://www.droid-life.com/2010/10/15/angry-birds-now-live-in-android-market/) are reporting that angry birds is available in the android market. However I can't find it on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S in New Zealand). I have tried the bar code, the download links and searching the android market from my phone the app just isn't there.

Whats going on?
Is my phone not supported?
Is my country not supported?
Is my OS version (2.1) not supported?

Comment: The game is so horribly addicting and fun, why would you even want it? ;)

Comment: Sorry. What I meant to say was I would contact Rovio.

Answer (score 3):

GetJar is where they first posted it and it got hammered. They got it on the Android Market pretty quickly, but Rovio's complaint (and why they went with an alternate market in the first place) is that a lot of people complained they couldn't find the beta in the Android Market.

A few people who were able to get it set up mirrors, including a Torrent. A quick web search should find an alternative download location for you, if you haven't already got it.

Comment: enjoy: http://www.mediafire.com/?j81foozdu2q5ph3

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have: http://www.appbrain.com/app/angry-birds/com.rovio.angrybirds

Comment: Using the barcode from that site gives "Not found The requested item could not be found." in the android market.

Comment: Back when I was having issues getting Angry Birds beta installed, AppBrain's FastWeb Installer managed to install it on my phone even when searching the market produced no results. May be worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

Your OS is supported. Your phone should be as well. Don't know about your country. I hate to speculate without know exactly what is going on, but honestly I've never seen anyone have all the trouble that Rovio is having getting their app visible to anyone in the market. Since the beta its been randomly blocked from rather unusual groups (Like Samsung Vibrant owners in the US) -- and all Rovio does is blame geographic restrictions in the market.

Anyway, all that explanation aside -- here's an alternative download for an ad-supported version: 
http://www.getjar.com/adp/angry-birds

Mobile version: http://m.getjar.com/adp/angry-birds

Comment: Even that link was way more painful then it needed to be!  Try: http://m.getjar.com/adp/angry-birds instead.

Comment: I will not be using getjar on principle. The place to get apps is the android market, anyone trying to bypass it will not be getting either my money or my ad impressions. I also will not support any service which requires me to give out my phone number.

Answer (score 2):

On a UK Galaxy S, I know that I couldn't find the beta version in the Market for ages, then Samsung released "2.1 update 1" and straight after I upgraded I could see angry birds in the Market, now the full versions there I can see that too.

Have your network released 2.1-update1 (aka build JM *x* ) for you yet, try checking with the Samsung Kies software.

Comment: Its available but I have not upgraded yet I was waiting for 2.2 which should be out by the end of the month.